# Lucas Number Sequence

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Can anyone help me in this question:

Define $ (b_n)$ as $b_1= 1,b_n=a_{n+1} - a_n $ for $ n\ge 2$, where $ a_n $ is the Fibonnaci series. This sequence is known as the sequence of Lucas numbers.

Prove:

(i)  $b_n=b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ for $ n \ge 3$

---

Here is what I have done:

$(a_n)=1,1,2,3,5,....$

$b_2=a_3 -a_2=2-1=1 $

I have to prove the equation through mathematical induction. So:

LHS
$(b_3)=a_4 -a_3=3-2=1 $

RHS
$b_2 + b_1 = 1 +1 =2 $

But here the LHS and RHS should be equal. So I looked up on wikipedia and there it says Lucas numbers are $2,1,3,4,7,11,18,... $

Can anyone clarify what is happening here?

Comment: If the $a_i$ are the Fibonaccis, then so are the numbers $a_{n+1}-a_n$, immediately, by the basic recurrence for the Fibonaccis. So that difference doesn't give you the Lucas numbers. So if you are reporting correctly what was asked of you, then someone goofed, and you might want to request clarification.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This question was in the book i'm using and thanks for the clarification.Looks like there are errors in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From definition $$b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}=a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=a_{n-1}=a_{n+1}-a_n=b_n$$The last two steps follow from the definition of [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and definition of $b_n$. Thus $b_n$ is also a Fibonacci number.